# Pass props to every component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm rendering a bunch of routes via a React Router, inside of a class and I need the components to have access to the instance of the class that is firing the render as it will contain an instance of a service factory etc.

However, I cannot find any information on passing props down to components rendered via React Router or more helpful for me, passing a prop down to every component rendered via React Router so they have it available for use.

Is this possible? If so, how?

A skimmed down version of my code:

```
var routes = {
  component : 'div',
  childRoutes : [{
    path      : '/',
    component : AppContainer
  }]
};

// Not a React Component. Need a value from here, to 
// be passed to the AppContainer
class App {
  render() {
   let foo = 'bar';

    ReactDom.render(
      <Router history={history}
              routes={routes} />,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
  }
}

// Rendered via React Router
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.foo); //bar
    return <div>{this.props.foo}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a root route component, you could consider a very simple option like this:

```
export default React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { propValue: someValueHere });
    }
});
```

That effectively does nothing other than create the child components you give it while also passing on some extra props of your choosing. It might not be your solution forever, but it's enough to get you started I hope.

Comment: here is the useful resource: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#routehandler

Comment: Hi @TwoStraws, that would work however I need to pass down the value from the class/file that is kicking off the initial render, which is the issue in this case. Any ideas on that?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could update your answer to include your current code; it would certainly give us all a better idea of which solution might best fit you.

Comment: @TwoStraws Updated to include an example of what I would like!